# Pinpoint table section within td tr table class

Tags: css

I am wanting to pinpoint the attribute size element which shows 3XL and make the width smaller. But I am struggling to pinpoint it in CSS!

[Website screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIdP1.png)

At the moment I have

```
table.variations td.value {
}
```

But this pinpoints the entire section of the column including the "clear" button. I have tried:

table.variations td.value .attribute_size {
    }

But this also does not work.
Please help!

Thanks!
Beck

Comment: Post the actual code - don't post images of code

Answer (score 0):

You have to pinpoint the select option within the `td.value` field. Then you can style it anyway you wish.

**HTML**

```
<table class="variations">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="size" name="attribute_size">
          <option>Choose an option</option>
          <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
          <option value="3XL">3XL</option>
        </select>
        CLEAR
      </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.variations td.value {
  font-size: 12px;
}
select#size {
 color: white; 
 background-color: blue;
 font-size: 42px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b92nhq8/29/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3b92nhq8).